# How to set the language to Swedish when users visit example.se and to French when visiting example.fr?

Tags: i18n-l10n, uri

I have a Drupal 7 website in 18 languages. The main URL is example.com and 18 other international domains are domain aliases of the main URL (example.de, example.fr, example.se, ...).

The Language detection and selection feature in Configuration currently selects the language based on the path of the URL (example.com/de, example.com/se, ...) but not based on the actual URL extention (example.de, example.se, ...).

**How can I set the language to Swedish when users visit example.se and to French when visiting example.fr?**

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards, Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On admin/config/regional/language/configure/url change the **Part of the URL that determines language** to *Domain*.

Then set up domains to all languagues: admin/config/regional/language/edit/LANGCODE

Comment: Works perfectly. I thought that feature was only for subdomains like se.example.com, but appearantly it works for both domains and subdomains. Thank you Gabor!

Comment: Putting session above URL in the language detection configuration alows for changing the language on example.fr to for example Swedish like so: example.fr?language=se. Drupal rocks!